# Maximum Profit for selling/buying stocks but we can only have absolute value of at most k shares

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I have a classic interview problem to ask but it is with a twist:

> You are given the stock prices for `n` days, `a1, a2, ..., an`. You are also given an integer `1 <= k <= n`. Each day, you can do one of three things:

> 1. do nothing
> 2. sell one unit of stock at the price of that day. (you can sell even if you don't have any stock in your portfolio as long as you are no more than `k` stocks in debt)
> 3. buy one unit of stock at the price of that day.

> But, **you can at any time have at most `k` stocks in your possession or you can be at most `k` stocks in debt.** So, for example, if you have `k` stocks, you can **not** buy any more stocks without selling some. Find the maximum profit you can make. Another example is that you can not sell more stocks without buying some if you are already `k` stocks in debt.

> You want to have *net zero* stocks after the `n`th day. Please do this more efficiently than `O(nk)` or `O(n^2)`. `O(n log k)` for instance.

I can do this in `O(nk)` using dynamic programming on the day number and *net* number of stocks in my possession. But how do I this more efficiently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're allowing yourself to be in debt, you can sort your prices. Furthermore, it seems like if `k <= n/2` a greedy strategy of picking the largest `k` values to sell and smallest `k` values to buy work maximize the profit.  Otherwise, you can adapt the above strategy and not necessarily buy/sell exactly `k` times if `k > n/2`. This approach would be dominated by the sort, which is O(N * log(N)) and meets your requirements.

Comment: @wLui155 you can have more than `k` deals, just not holding more than `k` at the same time

Comment: What are the solutions for [1] and [2, 1] (k = 10)? I assume the first is do nothing and the second is to sell for 2 and then buy for 1? I'm partly trying to understand if we must not end with any stock "debt." What does stock debt mean to the balance? If I just sell one stock for 2 and don't buy any what's the ending balance/profit?

Comment: @גלעדברקן stock debt means you sell a stock you didn't own (which means you must have borrowed 1 stock from somewhere). For your portfolio, it means "-1" to the net balance. (Buying a stock means "+1"). You are right in your scenario for [1] and [2, 1]. If you just sell a stock for 2 and don't buy any, your portfolio consists of -1 stock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in O(n log k) time.  There are different ways to think about the solution, but I think it's simplest to think of it as an optimization of the dynamic programming approach you already know about.

Let's say you want to iterate through the days, keeping track of the best cash position for each possible amount of shares held.  We'll say c<sub>i</sub> is the most cash you can have holding i shares.  To calculate a new day with price p, for each i you do c'<sub>i</sub> = max( c<sub>i-1</sub>-p, c<sub>i+1</sub>+p, c<sub>i</sub> ), finding the best way to get i shares by buying one, selling one, or holding respectively.

We can observe/prove some interesting properties of these cash positions:

1. As i increases, c<sub>i</sub> decreases monotonically -- it will always cost you more money to end up with more shares.
2. As i increases, the *difference* c<sub>i</sub> - c<sub>i+1</sub> increases.  Intuitively, this is because each difference is the price of some share that you could have bought/sold, and it's always better to buy the cheapest shares first or sell the more expensive shares first. Formally, we could prove it inductively.  Let's call this difference p<sub>i</sub>
3. When the best c<sub>i</sub> comes from buying a share, the same is true for all c<sub>j > i</sub>.  This is easy to prove from (2)
4. When the best c<sub>i</sub> comes from selling a share, the same is true for all c<sub>j < i</sub>.  This is similarly easy to prove from (2)

Because of property (2), we don't need to maintain a mapping from each i to a c.  We only need to maintain the *set of differences*, and best cash position for the smallest possible number of shares held.

Because of properties (3) and (4), the number of changes we need to make to the set of differences is bounded by a constant.  Each day you just add 2 copies of p to the set of differences, and then, if you have more than 2k differences, remove the highest and lowest.

If you maintain the set of differences in a balanced BST or similar structure, then these additions and removals take log(k) time, leading to an O(n log k) algorithm overall.

---

Example:

```
Normal DP table
K = 3
Cash positions by day and num held at EOD
PRICE    1   5   2   3   9   2   4
-----------------------------------
HELD: 3         -8  -6  -6   1   2 
      2     -6  -3  -1   3   6   6
      1 -1  -1   2   2   8   9  10
      0  0   4   4   5  11  12  13
     -1  1   5   6   7  14  14  16
     -2      6   7   9  16  16  18
     -3          8  10  18  18  20

DIFFS            5   5   9   5   4
             5   5   3   5   3   4
         1   5   2   3   3   3   3
         1   1   2   2   3   2   3
             1   1   2   2   2   2
                 1   1   2   2   2
```

Here's an implementation in Python, along with a slow DP implementation and a test to make sure they match.

This makes use of the `sortedcontainers` module, which you might have to `pip install`:

```python
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
from random import randint

def maxProfit(k, dailyPrices):
    minheld=0
    minheldcash=0
    diffs = SortedList()
    for price in dailyPrices:
        diffs.add(price)
        diffs.add(price)
        if minheld > -k:
            # can only get to new minheld by selling short
            minheld -= 1
            minheldcash += price
        else:
            # minheld doesn't change.  Can sell short or hold
            diffs.pop() # highest
            lo = diffs.pop(0) # lowest
            if lo < price:
                # better to sell
                minheldcash = minheldcash - lo + price
            # else better to hold

    # calculate profit for 0 held at end
    for _ in range(minheld,0):
        minheldcash -= diffs.pop(0)
    
    return minheldcash


def maxProfitSlow(k, dailyPrices):
    cash = [0]*(2*k+1)  # cash for holding, offset by k
    minheld = 0
    maxheld = 0
    for price in dailyPrices:
        if maxheld < k:
            maxheld += 1
            minheld -= 1
            cash[maxheld+k] = cash[maxheld+k-1] - price
            cash[minheld+k] = cash[minheld+k+1] + price
        newcash = [0]*len(cash)
        newcash[minheld+k] = max(cash[minheld+k], cash[minheld+k+1] + price)
        newcash[maxheld+k] = max(cash[maxheld+k], cash[maxheld+k-1] - price)
        for i in range(minheld+k+1, maxheld+k):
            newcash[i] = max(cash[i-1]-price, cash[i], cash[i+1]+price)
        cash = newcash
    return cash[k]


for _ in range(1000):
    k = randint(1,100)
    prices = [randint(1,100) for _ in range(randint(1,100))]
    if (maxProfit(k,prices) != maxProfitSlow(k,prices)):
        raise "Matt is wrong" # never happens ;-)

print("success")
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Timmermans, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I can not fully understand it and it seems too "magical" to me. I think it is due to my lack of background reading. Could you please tell me if this technique is a well-known approach or you came with it yourself? If it is well-known, where can I learn more about it? It would greatly help to me to then focus on that area. Thanks again!

Comment: No, sorry, this is very unusual and it took me two days to think it through.

Comment: Could you please help me understand why we don't need to iterate over the set of differences for each element? What does "add 2 copies of p" look like in practice?

Comment: @גלעדברקן  I added a worked example that should make that clear.  The differences are non-decreasing, so their corresponding hold amounts are determined by their numerical order.  All the diffs > price indicate buy positions, and all the diffs < price indicate sell positions.  You can find the divisions by BST search.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry for being so obtuse -- could you please add either code or the other state we need to keep in addition to the diffs in the example? I still don't follow fully how various scenarios might work. It looks like the "diffs" table/tree is just copies of prices per se, is that right?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I added an implementation too

Comment: @MattTimmermans How one can get the path (actions taken) that got to the optimum?

Comment: @danas.zuokas to determine the actual sequence of buy/sell actions, you need to remember 2 numbers, call them h and l, for each day, indicating that the best way to end up with >= h shares is to buy, and the best way to end up with <= l shares is to sell.  Then you can work backward from the end where you have 0 shares to determine what the best action was on each day.  On each day `h` is the HELD count *above* diffs equal to the day's price, and `l` is the number of HELD count below.  In order to determine these in log n time, you need to keep the diffs in an order statistic tree (google it)

Comment: @MattTimmermans Can this be extended to have different k (with 0 as a possible value) for long and short positions?

Comment: Yes, sure, it's relatively easy to change the upper and lower bounds, based on #shares held or amount of cash.