# Finding the path with max sum using DFS takes too long

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, maximum-profit-problem

At each time point agent can:

- open one position if he has enough funds. This reduces funds by current price. The price is added to the list of open positions
- close one position (the one opened farthest in time) if he has open positions. This adds current price to funds, removes position from the list and increases profit by current price minus open price.
- hold (do nothing).

Given an array of prices, the aim is to find optimal open/close moments to get maximum profit.

I have implemented this, but the code runs very long (1 minute for 16 observations). What are the possibilities for the improvement?

Also, I want to get the optimal path itself. I can not store all the paths. What's the algorithm for backtracking?

Here is the code using Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import time

def optimal_strategy(prices, root):
    s = deque([root])
    m = 0.0
    while s:
        n = s.pop()
        t = n['time'] + 1
        if t == len(prices):
            m = np.max([m, n['profit']])
            continue
        p = prices[t]
        s.append({'name': 'h' + str(t), 'time': t, 'parent': n['name'],
                  'funds': n['funds'], 'positions': n['positions'], 'profit': n['profit']})
        if p < n['funds']:
            s.append({'name': 'ol' + str(t), 'time': t, 'parent': n['name'],
                      'funds': n['funds'] - p, 'positions': n['positions'] + [p], 'profit': n['profit']})
        if len(n['positions']) > 0:
            s.append({'name': 'cl' + str(t), 'time': t, 'parent': n['name'],
                      'funds': n['funds'] + p, 'positions': n['positions'][1:], 'profit': n['profit'] + p - n['positions'][0]})

    return m

nobs = 16
np.random.seed(1)
prices = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=nobs))
plt.plot(prices)

t0 = time.time()
m = optimal_strategy(prices, {'name': 'r', 'time': -1, 'parent': None,
                              'funds': 4.0, 'positions': [], 'profit': 0.0})
print('Time {} Max {}'.format(time.time() - t0, m))
```

Comment: The post starts with terms like "agent", "position", "funds", "current price". Instead, could you first introduce the topic and post a description of the challenge that defines its terms before it uses them? Can you provide some examples of input and expected output? Your code produces `prices` with some negative values in them. What is the meaning of a negative price?

Comment: It's a stock trader (agent) who can buy (open) and sell (close) a stock (position) to increase initial funds (sum of money). For example, given stock prices [6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1] and initial sum 4. The best actions would be to buy at price1, sell at price 4 (profit 3) and buy at price 2, sell at price 6 (profit 4). Making total profit 7. And two paths leading to this outcome h0->h1->h2->ol3->ol4->cl5->cl6->ol7 and h0->h1->h2->ol3->ol4->cl5->cl6->h7.

Comment: I don't really understand the example. Are those stock prices for the same stock? Are they prices at different days? If the initial fund is 4 and the price is 1, why not buy four items for the whole fund, and sell it price 6 for each of them, getting 24, making a profit of 20? I don't understand.

Comment: It's the price of the same stock. Prices are at different days. Trader can buy and sell one stock.

Comment: So they cannot buy on two consecutive days? The transactions must be a sequence of buy-sell-buy-sell-buy-sell, and each transaction must be on a different day? Specifications are missing in your question.

Comment: They can buy on two (or any number) consecutive days, as long as they have enough sum of money available. In the example, buying is on days 3 and 4, selling is on days 5 and 6 (enumeration starts from 0).

Comment: DFS is not a great solution for this problem -- too many states.  Dynamic programming is better. The level 10 solution is like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77104162/maximum-profit-for-selling-buying-stocks-but-we-can-only-have-absolute-value-of/77109236#77109236

Comment: @MattTimmermans how to get the path (actions taken) that got to the optimum?

Comment: Just optimize funds, and use the fact that `parent` forms a linked list back to the root.

Comment: @danas.zuokas If you're asking about the linked answer, then comment on that one and I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example showing how to get the exact trades that lead to the maximum funds. Maximizing funds guarantees that we maximized profits. Detailed calculations about which trades earned what profit can be calculated after we know the sequence.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Trade = namedtuple("Trade", "time funds shares parent")

def optimal_strategy (prices, funds):
    root = Trade(-1, funds, 0, None)
    portfolios = [root]
    for i, price in enumerate(prices):
        # Start with the option of holding.
        next_portfolios = portfolios.copy()
        for portfolio in portfolios:
            # Can we sell?
            next_funds = portfolio.funds + price
            next_shares = portfolio.shares - 1
            if 0 <= next_shares and 0 <= next_funds:
                if next_portfolios[next_shares].funds < next_funds:
                    next_portfolios[next_shares] = Trade(
                        i, next_funds, next_shares, portfolio)
            # Can we buy?
            next_funds = portfolio.funds - price
            next_shares = portfolio.shares + 1
            if 0 <= next_funds:
                if len(next_portfolios) == next_shares:
                    next_portfolios.append(Trade(
                        i, next_funds, next_shares, portfolio))
                elif next_portfolios[next_shares].funds < next_funds:
                    next_portfolios[next_shares] = Trade(
                        i, next_funds, next_shares, portfolio)
        portfolios = next_portfolios

        # Remove portfolios that cannot lead to our answer.
        while len(prices) - i < len(portfolios):
            portfolios.pop()

    path = []
    portfolio = portfolios[0]
    parent_portfolio = portfolio.parent
    while parent_portfolio is not None:
        if parent_portfolio.shares < portfolio.shares:
            path.append((portfolio.time, 'buy'))
        else:
            path.append((portfolio.time, 'sell'))
        portfolio = parent_portfolio
        parent_portfolio = portfolio.parent
    return list(reversed(path))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution. What algorithm do you use? It's not immediately obvious, how optimal path is found, I don't see any max function.

Comment: @danas.zuokas I'm just using dynamic programming to find the optimal funds you can be left at,, and using `parent` as a linked list to reconstruct the path. The `max` is implicit in the fact that I only replace the portfolio if I improved the funds available. Worst case this is a `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Comment: Can you think of anything that can still improve the performance. Different data structure, any special data properties or algorithm corner cuts? Regardless, the performance improvement from my original implementation is tremendous.

Comment: @danas.zuokas I just added one optimization. Look for `Remove portfolios that cannot lead to our answer` for that. But fundamentally, no. While looking at each of `O(n)` of the prices we might have `O(n)` different amounts of shares, and that means we have to look at `O(n^2)` things. You'd need a very different algorithm to do better.

Comment: Can you explain the condition `0 <= next_funds` in sell part? I think it should be allowed to sell even if this leads to negative funds. In a situation, where all possible trades lead to losses, some path would still be with minimum losses. Also, indexing by the number of shares, how can it be changed in a situation where units are not integer values (ETFs, for example).

Comment: @danas.zuokas That line was my attempt to guess what negative prices mean. As for fractional valgues, the more possible values, the slower dynamic programming will be. I'd need to see a well specified problem to come up with a workaround.

Comment: If it were selling most profitable stock instead of the oldest, would that change the whole structure of the algorithm or would it be enough to sort `portfolios` by funds?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256616/discussion-between-danas-zuokas-and-btilly).